# jQuery plugin to add UserVoice-style feedback tab to a web page

Tags: jquery, plugins

Is there a jQuery plug-in out there that can mimic those fixed position tabs people use on their sites? The tab is usually fixed on the left or right hand side of the web page.

[UserVoice](https://uservoice.com/) provides a script to submit feedback, which adds a tab to your page (they have a feedback tab on their own page if you need an example).

Stack Overflow used UserVoice some time ago.

Comment: do you have an live example somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go, shameless plug, but I created this one:
http://wpaoli.building58.com/2009/09/jquery-tab-slide-out-plugin/

Give it a try, might be what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 from me. Also it looks like there has been a branch created on https://github.com/hawk-ip/jquery.tabSlideOut.js with some tweaks, if anyone comes across this answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can simply position an element with css by using "position: fixed; top: xy px; left: 0 px;"

by clicking on the image or the element you can load your backend system. For example [with jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

hope I'd understand your question right.

Comment: `position: fixed;` is not fully supported by all browsers.